# Can every vector space,V be written as direct sum decomposition of its proper subspaces which are T-invariant given T is a linear operator from V to V

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, direct-sum, invariant-subspace

Since there are linear operators which have no eigen values, that's why this question rose in my mind as whether every vector space can be written as direct sum decomposition of ***T-invariant*** **PROPER** ***subspaces*** or are there any exceptions to it ?

Comment: Having in mind Jordan form, I think that the endomorphism represented by the matrix with $1$s on the diagonal and the entries above the diagonal might not have proper invarant subspaces.

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ is a non-trivial rotation of $\mathbb{R}^2$, there is no $T-$invariant proper subspace.

Comment: How do you define this rotation?

Comment: $T : (x,y) \mapsto (\cos(\theta)x - \sin(\theta)y, \sin(\theta)x + \cos(\theta)y)$ where $\theta \neq 0 \text{ } [2\pi]$.